# Formula for the number of ` distinct permutations of N of one element and M of another element

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve amidst a larger problem. Suppose I have a `N` of some element and `M` of another element, say `N=2` `x`s and `M=3` `y`s. I want to find the number of distinct permutations of those, which would be

```
xxyyy
xyxyy
yxxyy
yxyxy
yyxyx
yyxxy
yyyxx
xyyxy
yxyyx
xyyyx
```

I guess another way of thinking about this is the number positions that `N` elements can occupy among `N+M` indices.

Is there a simple formula for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called [number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Formula for given case is ([factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) are used)

*(it is equal to the number of (n+m)-bit binary values containing m or n zero bits)*

```
C(N+M, N) = (N+M)! / (N! * M!)
```